# Code for appending to a certain index of an array

Tags: ruby

I have a collection which, after the code has ran, looks something like the following:

```
[
  { title: 'alpha', lines: [ { *some object* } ] },
  { title: 'bravo', lines: [ { *some object* } ] },
  { title: 'charl', lines: [ { *some object* } ] },
  { title: 'delta', lines: [ { *some object*, *some object 2*, *some object 3* } ] m},
  { title: 'echoo', lines: [ { *some object* } ] },
]
```

The way that I'm doing this is:

1. Check if there is an object in the outer array that has a matching `title`

   - If it doesn't exist, create that object with the `title` and `lines`
2. Check if inside `lines` there is an object that exists at the specific supplied index

   - If it doesn't exist, create the object at that index
   - Otherwise take the existing object at that index and append `val` to `a_or_b`

This method will get called multiple times per group i.e. 4 times for `alpha`, 4 times for `bravo`, and 4 times for each line in `delta`. There is currently one group (but there may be more in the future) which has more than one object inside the `lines`.

```
def data_with(data, val, group, date, nom, a_or_b, line_no = 0)
  # add this group if it doesn't exist
  if data.find { |x| x[:title] == group }.nil?
    data << { title: group, lines: [] }
  end

  # if the line at the line_no doesn't exist, create it
  if data.find { |x| x[:title] == group }[:lines][line_no].nil?
    data.find { |x| x[:title] == group }[:lines][line_no] = {
      date: date,
      nom: nom,
      a_or_b.to_sym => val
    }
  else # add to the value of the line at the line_no index
    data.find { |x| x[:title] == group }[:lines][line_no][a_or_b.to_sym] += val
  end
end
```

What are some ways I can improve this method?

Answer (score 1):

In general I think something feels off with your data structure and the naming of your parameters / variables is extremely difficult to understand (e.g. what is an `a_or_b`?).

Anyway, you could structure your code a bit more object oriented and extract helper methods. I don't know the full context of your application so this might be overkill. To provide some food for thoughts here is an example:

````rb
input = [
  { title: 'alpha', lines: [ { a_or_b: 1 } ] },
  { title: 'bravo', lines: [ { a_or_b: 1 } ] },
  { title: 'charl', lines: [ { a_or_b: 1 } ] },
  { title: 'delta', lines: [ { a_or_b: 1 } ] },
  { title: 'echoo', lines: [ { a_or_b: 1 } ] },
]

class Collection
  class Entry
    def initialize(data)
      @data = data
    end

    def ==(other)
      @data[:title] == other
    end

    def update_or_create_line_by(index:, date:, nom:, a_or_b:, value:)
      update_line_by(index: index, value: value, a_or_b: a_or_b) ||
        create_line_by(index: index, date: date, nom: nom, a_or_b: a_or_b, value: value)
    end

    def create_line_by(index:, date:, nom:, a_or_b:, value:)
      lines[index] = {
        date: date,
        nom: nom,
        a_or_b.to_sym => val
      }
    end

    def update_line_by(index:, value:, a_or_b:)
      return unless lines[index]

      lines[index][a_or_b.to_sym] += value
    end

    private

    def lines
      @data[:lines]
    end
  end

  def initialize(data)
    @data = data.map { |entry| Entry.new(entry) }
  end

  def find_or_create(title:)
    find_by(title: title) || create_by(title: title)
  end

  def find_by(title:)
    @data.find { |entry| entry == title }
  end

  def create_by(title:)
    entry = Entry.new(title)
    @data << entry
    entry
  end
end

def data_with(data, val, group, date, nom, a_or_b, line_no = 0)
  collection = Collection.new(data)
  entry = collection.find_or_create(title: group)
  entry.update_or_create_line_by(index: line_no, date: date, nom: nom, a_or_b: a_or_b, value: val)
end

data_with(input, 1, 'alpha', Time.now, 'nom', 'a_or_b', 0)
puts input
```
````